# search_tweets with UTF8 query in windows command line returns 0 output

Tags: r, command-line, utf-8, job-scheduling, rtweet

I have a script to scrape tweets using rtweet package in R. i am using the following code.

```
rt <- search_tweets(
  q = ("اجرک"), 
  n = 5000, 
  include_rts = FALSE,
  geocode = lookup_coords(),
  parse = TRUE,
  lang = 'ur',
  retryonratelimit = TRUE, 
  token = create_token()
)
```

The code works fine in Rstudio (create_token and lookup_coords have respective inputs that are removed here). I am able to get a few hundred tweets containing the search query. The aim is to run this script using Windows task scheduler. However when the same script is run using command line, e.g.

```
Rscript -e "source('path\\to\\script.R')"
```

the script runs but the resulting data frame has zero rows. Using my very limited understanding of debugging, I pinpointed the problem to the type of query given as input in the above said function. If I use Latin characters, for example 'ajrak', it does return a data frame with tweets in command line.
In short, the behaviour of the R script I have written is different in R studio versus Windows Command line. The main cause is the use of UTF-8 query. After searching around a lot, I could not find a solution. Any way to fix this problem?

Comment: Does `Sys.getlocale("LC_CTYPE")` return the same locale in Rstudio and R ran in CMD?

Comment: You could try setting `Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "en_US.UTF-8")` in the beginning of your script.

Comment: Both RStution and command line (type `R` in WIndows Console and then go to R prompt, type `Sys.getlocale("LC_CTYPE")`) return: `"English_United States.1252"`.
Added `Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "en_US.UTF-8")` at the start of the script, no effect.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use Linux or Mac
2. Use escaped unicode characters instead of utf8 text.